# Creating an Android Layout with 2 resizing views

Tags: android, android-layout

In my layout, I need a header, a list-view, and a footer with a `TextView`. The `TextView` needs to be resizable to up to 5 lines. Think facebook chat, where you have the blue header with the name of your friend, the middle content pane, and a text box down below, that grows as you type stuff in:

```
[header]     a fragment that takes up about 50dp
[content]
[content]
[content]
[content]    something like a ViewGroup with a ListView in it
[content]
[content]
[content]
[footer]     a ViewGroup that contains an EditText and Buttons
```

I've tried all sorts of different layout settings, but can't get it right. Either the footer takes up all the space, or the content covers the footer.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<LinearLayout ...>

    <!-- Slot to put Header fragment in -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Here's where the content goes. This is supposed to be a ListView
         inserted as a fragment -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        ... />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

I left out the `layout_width` and `layout_height` values empty, because I don't know what to set them to.

**UPDATES**
Initially, I thought the problem was because my `EditText` was set to `maxLines=5` and `TextMultiline`, but I tried removing everything but one button with a hardcoded height, and  the insert still covered everything. I also tried setting `<footer below="content">` but then `content` just covered `footer`

Comment: Did you at least tried my layout file? I really doubt it behaves like you said in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the `footer` layout included is another `RelativeLayout`. The `footer` layout contains elements that set `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, which made the footer layout take up the entire screen. I have no idea why it would do that, but that's what happens.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a UI like this create a layout

header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="xyz"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

for footer:

footer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="xyz"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Create another layout that will contain listView as you said :
main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 **<include layout="@layout/header.xml" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>**   
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        >
    </ListView>
 **<include layout="@layout/footer.xml" android:layout_below="@+id/listview" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>**   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: sorry, but your current answer covers up the `footer`.

Comment: @ceaser : try setting `android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"` in relative layout .. see my edited answer

Comment: That showed the `header`, `content`, and a 50dp gap at the bottom. The footer still wasn't there. My assumption is that the `footer` was moved `50 dp` up as well, and the `content` just covered it.

Comment: try `android:layout_marginBottom="-50dip"`

Comment: didn't work either. it just made `content` extend past the bottom of the screen, so the last couple of items in the list wouldn't appear.

Comment: hey now see i have edited some part in relative layout added gravity..it shud wrk

Comment: first, thanks for all the help. second, sorry, but that didn't work either haha. If you want, i can send you the code so you can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

check this...I hope it helps. At the moment I have defined an array.xml in Values folder with some empty entries for ListView. You will have to handle it with code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HEADER" />    

        <ListView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/chats"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </ListView>


        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="5"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint=" Please enter your Chat" />  

</LinearLayout>
```