# Have Android EditText extend upwards instead of downwards

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a chat layout that's somewhat similar to Facebook's and Yahoo! Messenger's, i.e. a `Fragment` header, a `ListView` of messages, and a `RelativeLayout` footer, which has an `EditText` and a bunch of `Buttons`.

```
[            HEADER            ]
 ______________________________
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|           Messages           |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|______________________________|
[BTN][    EditText   [IMG]][BTN]
```

When I type in long text, I want this:

```
[            HEADER            ]
 ______________________________
|                              |
|           Messages           |
|______________________________|
      ____________________
     |      EditText      |
     |                    |
     |                    |
     |                    |
[BTN][               [IMG]][BTN]
```

but instead, I get this:

```
[            HEADER            ]
 ______________________________
|                              |
|           Messages           |
|______________________________|
      ____________________
[BTN]|    EditText   [IMG]|[BTN]
     |                    |
     |                    |
     |                    |
     [                    ]
```

I tried setting the layout's `gravity="BOTTOM"`, but that didn't work. I tried using `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, but [that made the footer take up the entire screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12510814/152993).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by using a `LinearLayout`, `android:gravity="bottom"`, and wrapping the `EditText` and some other stuff into a `RelativeLayout`.